# Get int value from Enum in Visual Scripting (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, integer, bolt

I'm creating a game in Visual Scripting in Unity.
I created an enum in a C# Script because I read that we can't create Enum in Visual Scripting (if someone knows how to do it, I would be very grateful). Here is how I created it:

```
   public enum Speeds { Slow = 0, Normal = 1, Fast = 2, Faster = 3, Fastest = 4 };
   public Speeds currentSpeed;
```

Is there an easy way to get the integer value off the enum in Visual Scripting so I can have an equivalent to `(int)currentSpeed` ?

I tried to make a Switch on Enum but the result is not good and it seems very complicated to redo a simple C# line.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't question about unity like more on C# but here is your answer:
Just do what you did to `currentSpeed`. So....

```
int SpeedsEnumInt = (int)Speeds.Slow;
```

same if you have `currentSpeed`:

```
int SpeedsEnumInt = (int)currentSpeed;
```